# Debugging Gulp Build failure via SmartAdmin project

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm fairly new to Node JS, and trying to run gulp build to compile my project from a theme I bought. I've tried googling my issue and not having any luck really on what I need to look for. If someone could help me out with what I should be looking for or even know what the issue is.

Here is the error I'm getting, and this is from the smartadmin theme on wrapbootstrap.

When I get through all the processes of setup in html-seed directory, it's throwing this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Kevin Carson\Desktop\smartadmin-html-seed> gulp build                                                       module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'require-dir'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kevin Carson\Desktop\smartadmin-html-seed\gulpfile.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it it can't find a package. Run `npm install` from the same directory as your `package.json` to install the packages.

Comment: I originally had done that and it worked to a point, but looks like the author was able to determine that there was a new issue. I'll update my question with what I got just so you can see it. Thanks @rastalamm :)